# Multiplying column by -1 alters last digits of results using AWK

Tags: awk, floating-point

I have got pretty big data files and need to multiply my 2nd column by `-1`. The awk command looks like this:

```
awk '{printf "%.4f  %.16f\n", $1, $2*-1}' file > file_reverted
```

this works perfectly fine in some rows, but in some rows it somehow rounds down at the end instead of just adding a 0.

fine:

```
-0.094  0.0950083965247825  |  -0.0940  -0.0950083965247825
-0.0935 0.104569121568904   |  -0.0935  -0.1045691215689040
-0.093  0.114995049351066   |  -0.0930  -0.1149950493510660
```

wrong:

```
-0.0795 1.08856685504934    |  -0.0795  -1.0885668550493399
-0.079  1.16919985559016    |  -0.0790  -1.1691998555901599
```

After 16 decimals this is not too much of a problem but it still falsifies my results a little.

Comment: Do you always want to make the numbers negative?

Comment: no, I want to multiply every number by -1. It was just a coincidence that I only chose positive ones as example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, read [What every programmer should know about floating point arithmetic](http://floating-point-gui.de/). Or, if you prefer, [What very computer scientist should know about floating point arithmetic](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.22.6768).

Whether you see (-)1.0885668550493399 or (-)1.08856685504934 has nothing to do with the operation that you're making. **The numbers are the same** except for the sign.

```
$ echo 1.08856685504934 | awk '{printf "%.16f %.16f\n", $1, -$1}'      
1.0885668550493399 -1.0885668550493399
```

What's happening is that you're printing the numbers with more precision than what is stored. The difference between the printed numbers is 10<sup>-16</sup>, which is less than 2<sup>-52</sup> times the number, so is not expressible in the 52-bit mantissa of awk's floating point numbers. That's necessary to retain the precision across stages of printing out and parsing in. `1.0885668550493399` and `1.08856685504934` are representations for the same number.

Your results are not being falsified. You're getting the same result. Make sure to calculate the precision of your result — it's probably a lot less than the 52-bit precision of a floating-point value, as each stage of the calculation performs some rounding.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. Read the first article. The second link doesn't work on my side. Maybe you wanna check the link or maybe it is just viewable with permission.

Comment: @Ueffes the link didn't work to me either. Looking for the title I found several copies of it, for example http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: @Ueffes It's working for me, though the site is a bit slow (it took a few seconds to reply). You don't need any permission, citeseer is a public site.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to change the number of decimal places compared to the input then doing this should work:

`awk '{if($2<0){gsub(/-/,"",$2)}else if($2>0){$2="-"$2};print $1,$2}'`

The floating point representation of the number isn't displayed, getting rid of the precision problem.

Comment: Thank you, your answer is a very good solution for me. I chose Gilles' answer as the correct one because he explained the problem in a really good way. This way others can understand their fault quicker.

Comment: Yes, I agree Gilles provides a far clearer explanation.  Don't forget to handle negative numbers in the 2nd column though!